# How to Iterate over a column in a data frame to change its values

Tags: r, loops, function-calls

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
ID     A     B    
 0     8    25  
 1    16   123  
 2     4   120  
...             ...
```

What I want to do now is to iterate over column 'A' for example and call a function with the value of the cell and return it at the same location.

For example a function like (x^2)-1.

```
int calculation(int val){
   return val*val-1;
}

...code...

while(i<A.length){
  A[i] = calculation(A[i]);
}
```

So the result should look like this.

```
ID     A     B    
 0    63    25  
 1   265   123  
 2    15   120  
...             ...
```

---

I am new to R, if you know some good basic guidelines or books for scientific plotting, let me know. :-)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just `df$A <- (df$A^2) - 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very straightforward task in R.

```
a<-c(8,16,4)
b<-c(25,123,120)
df<-data.frame(a,b)

calculation<-function(a){
  a^2-1
}


# Method 1
df$a<-(df$a^2)-1

# Method 2
df$a<-calculation(df$a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple example using your `data.frame` (say df)

```
#Define your function as
calcualtion <- function(x){
  x*x - 1
}

#Suppose you want to call it on column A. Use sapply function as
df$A <- sapply(df$A, calcualtion)

result:
  ID   A
1  0  63
2  1 255
3  2  15
```

Comment: you don't need `sapply` to such a simple calculation on a column; imo it is overkill

Comment: @Jaap I just wanted to show-cause different ways to achieve it. I agree using `sapply` in such trivial case is not optimum use.

Comment: This would be a good answer if you explained vectorization a little bit and provided guidance for *when* `sapply` might be needed vs when it is not. As-is, I think it will be more confusing than helpful for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of R is its simplicity. 
If you would like to apply some operation for column `A`:

```
df[["A"]] = ((df[["A"]]*df[["A"]]) - 1)
```

Also, I would strongly recommend googling "vectorization in R".